# How to handle errors in an Observable chain conditionally?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using [`onErrorReturn`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html) to emit a particular item rather than invoking `onError` if the observable encounters an error:

```
Observable<String> observable = getObservableSource();
observable.onErrorReturn(error -> "All Good!")
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
          .subscribe(item -> onNextAction(),
              error -> onErrorAction()
          );
```

This works fine, but I want to consume the error in `onErrorReturn` *only if certain conditions are met*. Just like rethrowing an exception from inside a `catch` block.

Something like:

```
onErrorReturn(error -> {
    if (condition) {
        return "All Good!";
    } else {
        // Don't consume error. What to do here?
        throw error; // This gives error [Unhandled Exception: java.lang.Throwable]
    }
});
```

**Is there a way to propagate the error down the observable chain from inside `onErrorReturn` as if `onErrorReturn` was never there?**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `onErrorResumeNext` I guess you can achieve what you want

```
observable.onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
              if(errorOk)
                  return Observable.just(ok)
              else
                  return Observable.error(error)
          })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
          .subscribe(item -> onNextAction(),
              error -> onErrorAction()
          );
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create an method that will receive this error normally, something like

```
private void onError(Throwable error) {
// do whatever you want with your error
}

...
.onErrorReturn( error -> onError(error) )
```